# How to retry a Delphi TAdsConnection with ADT tables

Tags: database, delphi, data-binding, error-handling, advantage-database-server

From what I can see my Membership software connects to a number of tables using the following code in the FormCreate procedure:

```
 {Open the Sessions}
  Membership.LoginPrompt := False;
  Membership.Username := 'ONLINE';
  Membership.Password := '#######';
  Membership.ConnectPath := MembershipLocation;
  Membership.IsConnected := True;
  PosConnection.ConnectPath := PosLocation;
  PosConnection.IsConnected := True;
  Bookings.ConnectPath := BookingsLocation;
  Bookings.IsConnected := True;
  Local.ConnectPath := LocalLocation;
  Local.IsConnected := True;

  // Open all the tables
  for Wk1 := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do
    begin
    {Skip the Tmp / New Tables}
    if ((Components[Wk1] is TAdsTable) and (TAdsTable(Components[Wk1]).Name = 'NewTable')) then
      Continue;
    if ((Components[Wk1] is TAdsTable) and (TAdsTable(Components[Wk1]).Name = 'TmpTable')) then
      Continue;
    {Is it a TTable}
    if Components[Wk1] is TAdsTable then
      TAdsTable(Components[Wk1]).Active := True;
    {Is it a TwwTable}
    if Components[Wk1] is TwwTable then
      TwwTable(Components[Wk1]).Active := True;
    {Is it a TQuery}
    if Components[Wk1] is TAdsQuery then
      TAdsQuery(Components[Wk1]).Active := True;
    end;


  {Activate the Membership Tables. This is due to passwords}
  Members.Active := True;
  MemTypes.Active := True;
  MembersById.Active := True;
  MemBookMSys.Active := True;

  {Rebuild the Secondry index on the MemBook table}
  if RebuildIdx = True then
    begin
    MemBook.Active := False;
    MemBook.Exclusive := True;
    MemBook.Active := True;
//  Check(DbiRegenIndexes(MemBook.Handle));
    MemBook.Active := False;
    MemBook.Exclusive := False;
    MemBook.Active := True;
    end;
  {Make the Table Active}
  MemBook.Active := True;
```

Occasionally when the server isn't ready yet the connection fails and the user gets an Advantage error 7.xxx

I need it to retry connection a number of times, or again after a certain amount of time has passed.

Is there a standard way of error catching and retrying connection for this scenario? Or should I simply repeat the code after a certain amount of time has passed?

Thanks

Comment: You mentioned 7000 class errors.  7000 class errors are typically "table open" errors and not "connection errors" (Those are usually 6000 class errors).
Likely it is the attempt to open the table in exclusive mode (to rebuild the index) that is receiving the errors.    Just an observation.  I agree with the answer below of using standard try/catch, but if it is a 7000 class error you may want to just retry the table open rather then disconnecting/reconnecting.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that Edgar... Apologies it probably is infact a 6000 error as you say, it was a colleague who saw the original error. I'll need to test it but as I believe the drive on which POS (point of sale) Connection Path resides takes a few seconds to allocate, I should just retry the connection as Ken describes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use standard `try..except` handling.

```
function TYourDataModule.ConnectToDatabases: Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;

  Membership.LoginPrompt := False;
  Membership.Username := 'ONLINE';
  Membership.Password := '#######';
  Membership.ConnectPath := MembershipLocation;
  PosConnection.ConnectPath := PosLocation;
  Bookings.ConnectPath := BookingsLocation;
  Local.ConnectPath := LocalLocation;

  // Try to make all the connections together. If any fail, we'll
  // hit the except block.
  try
    Membership.IsConnected := True;
    PosConnection.IsConnected := True;
    Bookings.IsConnected := True;
    Local.IsConnected := True;
  except
    on E: EAdsDatabaseError do
    begin
      // Make sure all connections are closed, in case
      // one or more succeeded before a failure. We'll
      // be set for next time.
      Membership.IsConnected := False;
      PostConnection.IsConnected := False;
      Booking.IsConnected := False;
      Local.IsConnected := False;
      Result := False;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Your calling code then can use the function in a loop until it returns true, or exceeds the number of attempts:

```
var
  NumTrys: Integer;
const
  MAX_TRYS = 10;
  TRY_DELAY = 1000;
begin
  NumTrys := 0;
  while NumTrys < MAX_TRYS do
  begin
    if YourDataModule.ConnectToDatabases then
      Break;
    Inc(NumTrys);
    Sleep(TRY_DELAY);
  end;
  if NumTrys = MAX_TRYS then
    // Handle not being able to connect after all attempts.
end;
```

Note that you'll see the exception message on connection failures when running in the IDE, but not at runtime. If you don't want to see them in the IDE, you can turn off handling of EADSDatabaseError in the Project Options dialog.

Comment: Ken this is probably exactly what I'm looking for thanks :) Though I'm not sure whether the error would be caught at .IsConnected or at .Active, as I've just noticed the latter is used elsewhere in the code.

Comment: You can use the same type logic around the `Active` code; it's typically used when opening tables or queries. Also, see @Edgar's comment to your original question; I hadn't caught the series of error code you were getting, but as he says 7xxx errors are typically table or query related rather than connection.

Comment: Thanks ken, I believe is specifically the POS connection path being unavailable in this case. I should check to see what a reasonable amount of delay will be before a retry, and display a suitable user friendly message. Cheers

Comment: I had success activating the tables on the first retry (10 seconds) however the program freezes when it tries to call pass information to an associated program running from that location. I believe the location is some kind of terminal server. But that's probably an issue for another post :p